# Текущая дата в 24-х форматном поясе

Tags: php, дата

Хочу получить текущую дату, но в формате 24 часов, а не 12

```
$time = strtotime('-1 hours ');
echo date('d.m.Y h:i:s A', $time);
```

Вычитаю час,чтобы с московским выровнять, а вот как сделать,что было не 12 45, а 0 45

Comment: Заглавная H: `H:i:s`

Comment: @vp_arth Неа,не помогает

Comment: Помогает, вероятно у вас там полночь, а не полдень. `1:00:00 AM`, не так ли?

Comment: Да,именно, но даже если +15 часов,выдает не все равно в 12 ти форматном   $time = strtotime('+15 hours ');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s A', $time);

Comment: https://3v4l.org/0PoMu

Comment: хм, echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."\n"; показывает 14 часов сейчас,а  по Москве сейчас час ночи и 9 число еще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 24ч формат с ведущим нулём - H

И не нужно вручную вычислять разницу в часовых поясах

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."\n"; // В Москве сейчас
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('+12 hours')); // В Москве через 12ч
```

Код выше меняет часовой пояс для всех дальнейших вызовов.
В объектном стиле есть возможность более аккуратного применения часового пояса:

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow') );
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Документацию по функции [`date`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) не вариант прочитать?

[image: date]